# Is the centroid of plane a point on it

Tags: polygon, plane, centroid

I want to know if the centroid of a plane can actually be treated as a point on the plane.I have a few points on the plane from which i deduced the centroid.I would like to know if i substitute this in the plane equation will it be valid.

Thanks,
Harsha.

Answer (score 0):

More of a math question.  Answer will depend on which definition of centroid you want.   If you define the centroid as the intersection of straight lines that divide the plane in 2 by moment, then clearly every line is in the plane so all their intersections must also be.

Comment: This centroid is calculated as the mean of all the points of the plane available.